# AForge - Butterworth Low-Pass Filter - How do I create a ComplexImage from Complex[,] array?

Tags: c#, filter, aforge

I'm attempting to implement a Butterworth low-pass filter in C# using AForge. I have created the following function:

```
    public static ComplexImage ButterworthLP(double freq, double power, ComplexImage inImage)
    {
        int ydim = inImage.Height;
        int xdim = inImage.Width;
        Complex[,] imgData = inImage.Data;

        for(int v = 0; v<ydim; ++v)
        {
            for(int u = 0; u<xdim; ++u)
            {
                int dv = (v < ydim / 2) ? v : v - ydim;
                int du = (u < xdim / 2) ? u : u - xdim;
                double dist = (double)(dv * dv + du * du);

                // Apply filter
                double filter = 1 / (1 + Math.Pow(dist / (freq * freq), power));
                imgData[v, u].Re *= filter;
                imgData[v, u].Im *= filter;
            }
        }
        ComplexImage cImg = new ComplexImage(xdim,ydim);
        return cImg;
    }
```

The ComplexImage.Data property is read-only; so, currently, I'm getting the data and modifying it. I would now like to create a ComplexImage using this modified Complex data array, but I have yet to figure out how to do so. If there is an alternative method for modifying the input image data, I am open to suggestions, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation

> The constructor is protected, which makes it impossible to instantiate
>   this class directly. To create an instance of this class
>   FromBitmap(Bitmap) or FromBitmap(BitmapData) method should be used.

and as you have discovered the data is read only

So basically i think you'll have to download the source, and customize it to add your filter

Additionally you can try their discussion forums which might be more direct help

Comment: Thanks! I wrote on the forum, as you suggested. Apparently, you don't get a copy of the data array with the .Data property, but a reference to it instead. So, if imgData changes, the input ComplexImage changes.